# Open terminator, but there is root terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome-terminal

Ubuntu 32bit. I want to open terminator terminal by pressing shortcut Ctrl + Alt + T. But on the left panel appears pinky launcher icon and the name of the terminal is root terminal. It just the same terminator terminal, but the name and icon is different

I tried this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

And what i got:

```
  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/terminator               50        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm               20        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/lxterm                   30        manual mode
* 4            /usr/bin/terminator               50        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/uxterm                   20        manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/xterm                    20        manual mode
```

I tried to choose 0 and 4, it doesn't work like that

Also removing configs (including hidden directories), all data of Terminator, adding new profiles, install it again, doesn't work. I also choose a different shortcut, but still same result

So, if i open gnome-terminal and type terminator, everything opens and works without any problems, just native icon and the name

Comment: The difference isn't in the *package*, but in the `.desktop` (or equivalent) launcher, e.g., a line with `Exec=`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey thanks, it was gksu application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

I found the string 'Root Terminal' here:

```
/usr/share/applications
```

Just typed command in this directory:

```
sudo grep -Ril "Root Terminal" .
```

In file gksu.desktop was a root terminal, the application known as gksu:

*GKSu is a library that provides a Gtk+ frontend to su and sudo. It supports login shells and preserving environment when acting as a su frontend. It is useful to menu items or other graphical programs that need to ask a user's password to run another program as another user.* nongnu.org/gksu/

How did it get on my computer I dunno :)

So, typed remove package command:

```
sudo apt-get remove gksu
```

Everything is fine, Ctrl + Alt + T opens terminator